# Javascript function not working properly

Tags: javascript

Ok, so i've got the following javascript on my website to countdown timer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function timer(elementid, totaltime, format, color, style, trigger_a, trigger_b, done) {

  var hours = 0; var minutes = 0; var seconds = 0;

  if (totaltime > 0) {

    while (totaltime >= 3600) { hours++; totaltime -= 3600; }
    if (hours < 10) { hours = '0' + hours; }
    while (totaltime >= 60) { minutes++; totaltime -= 60; }
    if (minutes < 10) { minutes = '0' + minutes; }
    seconds = totaltime;
  }

  function display() {

    if (hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 0) {

      if (trigger_a == "reload") { location.href="page.php"; }
      else if (trigger_a == "enable" && trigger_b != "") { document.getElementById(trigger_b).disabled = false; }
      else { /* do nothing */ }

      document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML = done;      
    }

    else {

      var output = '';

      if (seconds > 0 && seconds <= 59) { seconds--; if (hours < 10) { hours = '0' + hours; } }
      else {
        if (minutes > 0 && minutes <= 59) { minutes--; if (minutes < 10) { minutes = '0' + minutes; } }
        else {
          if (hours > 0) { hours--; minutes = 59; }
        }
        seconds = 59;
      }

      if (hours > 0) {        
        if (format == 'long') { output += hours + " hours "; }
        else if (format == 'small') { output += hours + "h "; }
      }

      if (minutes > 0) {       
        if (format == 'long') { output += minutes + " minutes "; }
        else if (format == 'small') { output += minutes + 'm ';}
      }

      if (seconds < 10) { seconds = '0' + seconds; }
      if (format == 'long') { output += seconds + ' seconds'; }
      else if (format == 'small') { output += seconds + 's'; }

      if (color == '') {

        if (style == 'bold') { document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML = '<b>' + output + '</b>'; }
        else { document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML = output; }
      }

      else {

        if (style == 'bold') { document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML = '<font color='+color+'><b>' + output + '</b></font>'; }
        else { document.getElementById(elementid).innerHTML = '<font color='+color+'>' + output + '</font>'; }
      }      
      setTimeout(display, 1000);
    }
  }
  display();  
}
</script>
```

I add a span box like this:

```
<?php
$time_left = $from_database['time_left']; //timestamp;
?>
<span id="test"></span>
<script>
timer("test", "<?php echo $time_left - Time(); ?>", "long", "", "", "enable", "unlock_this", "Done");
</script>

<input type="submit" id="unlock_this" <?php if ($time_left - Time() > 0) { echo 'disabled'; } ?> />
```

The problem is, that when I refresh this page (after $time_left), the 'Done' message is not being displayed and I get a javascript error (document.getElementById = null) which directs back to

```
else if (trigger_a == "enable" && trigger_b != "") { document.getElementById(trigger_b).disabled = false; }
```

It's probably just a little thing, but i can't figure out what i've done wrong, so please help.

Comment: Do you expect the "done" message to be present after the page reload? Javascript doesn't survive a page reload.

Comment: the reload function aint important, in this case i'm talking about manual refresh (F5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though the problem is simply that you execute the `timer` function before the input with the `unlock_this` id has had a chance to load. I realise you've put a delay in with the `setTimeout` call of `display` but have you tried putting the script below the `input` element?

Or better still calling `timer` when the whole window has loaded? The easiest way to do the second of these options would be:

```
window.onload = function () {
    timer("test", "<?php echo $time_left; ?>", "long", "", "", "enable", "unlock_this", "Done");
};
```

But you are already using the `onload` property of the window, you will need to load it in a smarter way (either by using a library like JQuery, or by safeguarding existing functions with a wrapper function).

Comment: i do have the jquery.js included in my <head>

Comment: it seems to work moving it to a lower part of the code, stupid mistake i guess, thanks tho!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that with your html looking like

```
<span id="test"></span>
<script>
timer("test", "<?php echo $time_left - Time(); ?>", "long", "", "", "enable", "unlock_this", "Done");
</script>

<input type="submit" id="unlock_this" disabled />
```

by the time timer(), which calls display(), is called, the input with id "unlock_this" has not yet been parsed and added to the browsers DOM.

You should delay the call to timer() until the browser has finished parsing the document, like so:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    timer("test", "<?php echo $time_left - Time(); ?>", "long", "", "", "enable", "unlock_this", "Done");
}
</script>
```

Not though that this method will overwrite any previously added window.onload handlers.